# Getting data from a ParseQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

So I'm working on a new app using a Parse backend. The activity I am working on uses a recyclerview and cards to display a list of data. I've built the adapter, viewholder, etc and have tested that it works when I manually supply data. However, when I try and retrieve the data from parse, it never makes it into the view. For example, in the code below everything inside the done method is working correctly, but as soon as I'm outside of it bars is empty. The final Log.d line should be printing out the name of the first object in the ArrayList, but it never does. The toast makes the app crash on an invalid index because it says bars is still 0... aka the data is never added to it. I've tried every hack I can think of to get the data out of the query, but it never works. Any ideas?

```
       ArrayList<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();    
        ParseQuery<BarObj> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BarInfo");
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<BarObj>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<BarObj> Barlist, ParseException e) {
                            if(e == null){
                                for(int i=0; i<Barlist.size(); i++){
                                    String name = Barlist.get(i).getName();
                                    Double gender = Barlist.get(i).getGender();
                                    Integer cover = Barlist.get(i).getCover();
                                    Double line = Barlist.get(i).getLine();
                                    Double capacity = Barlist.get(i).getCapacity();
                                    Bar bar = new Bar(name, gender, cover, line, capacity);
                                    bars.add(bar);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                Log.d("bar", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
       Toast.makeText(this,bars.get(0).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.d("bars", "First bar is " + bars.get(0).getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're exetuting query method in background ie async, it's execution finishes after the lines in which you're trying to show Toast. That's why the `bars` list size is 0 when you're trying to get first element of it.

In the end of the `done()` method try to add the bars list to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it to show data